# increase Idea "reopen project" list size

Tags: intellij-idea, android-studio

Is there a way to increase the size of the recent projects list you get when you use "reopen project"? I found no setting for this - but perhaps there is some magic number I can tweak in some file?!

Comment: I found an answer (see below)

Comment: @vikingsteve nice! unfortunately Registry is not available on Android-Studio - have only found it in Idea 14

Comment: If you create a plugin in IntelliJ 14 and the have `initComponent` method do this: `Registry.get("ide.max.recent.projects").setValue(50);`, install plugin in android studio.

Comment: I made a simple plugin for android studio, would you like to test it out? (link in answer below)

Comment: @vikingsteve awesome - will try this after work

Comment: Did it work for you?

Comment: yea - was just able to try - looks good - thanks a lot!

Comment: great! thanks for testing it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Sorry! This is actually possible after all.

Use *ctrl+shift+a* to enter an action and type `Registry`.

From here, search for the key in the list named `ide.max.recent.projects`

Edit as appropriate (I have gone with 50 =).

Plus, for Android Studio, you can use this plugin: [Recent Projects Extender](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/7684)